# Draw Text along a path

Tags: c#, direct2d, sharpdx

I need to draw text along a curved path/bezier. Does somebody happen to have a tutorial ready or even some sample code to digest?

Thx

Fortis

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [already such a sample on MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Animating-Text-on-a-Path-883382a0#content), which although is C++, you may be able to adapt to C#.

From the description:

> This sample shows how to use Direct2D and DirectWrite to render a string of text along an animated, non-linear geometric path. The app renders "Hello, World!" repeated several times in different languages along a Bezier curve. The font style and size is constant.